# VBA Excel - Unloading form leads to entire application termination

Tags: excel, vba

I am calling a userform **A** from within another userform **B**. The problem arises when I try to close the userform **B**. I don't want to use **Hide** method, because there are some default values assigned to form properties in the form's Load method - and I would like these values to be reassigned every time the user closes up and opens the form during one session.
So it appears that I should use `Unload Me`, but the latter stops my entire application as if I used `End` command.

So the question is, why Unload Me shuts down the entire application, rather than a single form.

**Edit:** Using Unload showUserFormB instead of Unload Me does not help

```
Private Sub methodOfUserFormA()
   Call FormB.showUserFormB(some_params)
   Unload SqlUpload__handlePhantomRows
   Msgbox "Why Unload method shuts down entire app?"
End Sub
```

Comment: instead of using `Me` how about `UserFormB.Unload`? Using the more explicit name may avoid confusion in VBA as to which `Me` is being referred to.

Comment: could you post the code?  To my knowledge,`Unload Me` should only close the form you're calling from.

Comment: Where are you storing the form B properties and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I do not "store" them anywhere, I just assign defaults in the Form B's "Load" method